# Additional parameters for devise model on sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Devise for my users in my rails app. When people sign up its only their email and password. How do I have access to the controller to permit more param such as first name and last name?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the parameters to the `devise_parameter_sanitizer` for `sign_up`

This can be done in your `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name
  end
end
```

or configure the whole set of parameters using

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :email, :first_name, :last_name) }
end
```

Another way is to create a class that inherits from `Devise::ParameterSanitizer`

```
class User::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
  def sign_up
    default_params.permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :email, :first_name, :last_name)
  end
end
```

Then in your `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protected

  def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    User::ParameterSanitizer.new(User, :user, params)
  end
end
```